# How to add an Assistant or Staff Level in getOrgChart

Tags: orgchart

I'm analyzing OrgChart to use it in a specific project. Is there a way to add an staff or assistance level?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use different color for assistance and staff. Here is an example:

http://www.getorgchart.com/Demos/Box-Color